# Set gravity for RemoteView in android through java

Tags: android, android-widget, gravity

How i can set the gravity through java code in android,i have a Remoteview like this 
 `RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);`
i want to add gravity through java code.i tried using this way ,but it is not successfull.

```
 views.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on the type of View you want to call the method on. If it's e.g. a LinearlLayout, this will do the job:

```
rv.setInt(R.id.MyView, "setGravity", Gravity.CENTER);
```

I tested it on a LinearLayout and a TextView and it does work with the layout but not with the  TextView. So my assumption would be it's supported by ViewGroup classes only (you can check that assumption yourself by checking the setGravity(int) methods in the Android source for 
@android.view.RemotableViewMethod annotations).

So if you want to change TextView's gravity programmatically, you need to wrap the TextView in its own LinearLayout and change gravity of the LinearLayout instead, e.g. use this layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/day_header_title_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/day_header_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and set gravity like this:

```
rv.setInt(R.id.day_header_title_wrapper, "setGravity", Gravity.CENTER);
```

Comment: Maybe if you elaborate on the "not working" part then I could give some advise

Comment: @EmanuelMoecklin, yes it does not work for me too. It is linear layout on a widget. And it does not change after I set according to your answer.

Comment: @stuckedoverflow the idea is to have the TextView as your content and LinearLayout as your TextView's style holder. Ex; background, size etc.. So when you change gravity, the TextView will move inside the LinearLayout to mock the TextView gravity effect. Hope this helps after 6 years :D